# Sencha Touch and Saving Local Media

Tags: iphone, ios, sencha-touch, storage, extjs

Does anyone know if it is possible to save media from the internet on the local device using Sencha Touch?  From what I've seen so far, I understand it's definitely possible to save XML or JSON data locally on the device, but I have had no luck finding ways to store media locally.

To be more specific, I am looking to program an app that provides the user with a series of audio seminars - like podcasts, really.  The user would be able to stream those audio files directly from the internet, but I also need to provide the user with the ability to save an episode/seminar for later.  This will be important for when a user is traveling and does not have a reliable internet connection or data plan.

The primary delivery device would be on iOS (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch) and I would hope to be able to use the same technology on Android devices - but that would be a secondary phase.

If this is possible, how would I go about saving material?  And what, if any, would be the limitations on doing so? Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something similar using Sencha Touch 1 and PhoneGap to produce a hybrid app.

Basically, I use Sencha Touch to download the JSON, etc and LocalStorage to hold the data. Downloading media/files/etc to the actual device is not supported in Sencha Touch as the framework doesn't have access to a file system.

I then use PhoneGap's API's to tap into the device's native file system and download files to the app's Documents directory and pass the file names/paths to Sencha Touch for use in the app.

I'm assuming you are looking to create a hybrid app based on your question but if this is strictly a web app then there isn't much you can do.

TO add to the above point, you possibly could base64 encode the file and store it within LocalStorage but this isn't a sustainable model as LocalStorage only gives you 5mb of space. If you go over 5mb, the user is prompted (yes, no) to allow LocalStorage to use more space (in 5mb increments). Since the files your reference have the potential to be 5mb each, you can see how this could quickly become unmanageable for both you and the user.

EDIT:
See http://phonegap.com/ for the native wrapper
http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/2056122828/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url-all-the-code for the phonegap download plugin
and https://github.com/aaronksaunders/FileDownLoadApp for the code

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This gives me a lot of hope, especially since there's already code out there to help me get started.  I'm open to the idea of doing a hybrid app, which is why porting the same application to other devices is a secondary goal.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this website](http://www.sencha.com/learn/taking-sencha-touch-apps-offline/) out. Scroll down to storing data offline. They discuss Sencha Touch provides a set of data store and proxy classes that make it very easy to work with data from (and going to) a variety of sources - both server- and client-side... hope this helped, cheers.